# Global variables for unit tests in SailsJS app

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I'm working on a Sails app, and for my unit tests, I need to use some variable in ./test/bootstrap.test.js and in ./test/unit/controllers/*.test.js. I think about global variables, but how can I create them ?

I could create something like ./config/mydatatest.js with something like :

```
module.exports.myconf = {    
    anyobject: {
      bar: "foo"
    }
};
```

But is there any way to create mydatatest.js in the test directory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the idea of considering *test* as a specific environment like *development* or *production*. You could create an [environment-specific file](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/configuration) *`config/env/test.js`* to put the configuration:

```
/**
 * Test environment settings
 */
module.exports = {  
  myconf: {
    anyobject: {
      bar: "foo"
    }
  }
};
```

Then, you could add `NODE_ENV=test` to the command that launch the tests (based on [the example from the documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/testing))

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js",
  "debug": "node debug app.js",
  "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha test/bootstrap.test.js test/unit/**/*.test.js"
},
```

I use this technique to use `sails-memory` adapters when I run my tests.

Answer (score 1):

How about insert it in your `bootstrap.test.js`?

```
before(function (done) {
  Sails.lift({
    port       : 5031,
    log        : {
      level: 'error'
    },
    myconf     : {
      anyobject: {
        bar: "foo"
      }
    }
  }, function (err, server) {
    sails = server;
    done(err);
  });
});
```

Basically it **can**. If you want to put in separate file/ folder, just require them in your `bootstrap.test.js` inside your `myconf` like my example.